# iphone how to post audio or .caf on php server asynchronous

Tags: iphone

in my application i need to record sound .after this i need to post sound file on php server asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

consider to use ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ . It is a handy framework to make http connections.

This example is good for your question:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];


    // Upload a file on disk
    [request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
    forKey:@"photo"];

    // Upload an NSData instance
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```